# Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Calendar usage limits exceeded. [403] while inserting events

Tags: calendar, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

After clearing the calendar, I tried to insert the bunch of event in the Google Calendar.

The service inserts couple of events after that it gives error as :

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Calendar usage limits exceeded. [403]
Errors [
        Message[Calendar usage limits exceeded.] Location[ - ] Reason[quotaExcee
ded] Domain[usageLimits]
]
```

What could be the problem ??

I have tried the exponential back-off process.

```
var recurringEvent = calendarService.Events.Insert(newEvent, "primary");

recurringEvent.SendNotifications = true;

//exponential back-off
Retry.Do(() => recurringEvent.Execute(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

Comment: presumably you exceeded your usage quota. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/pricing?hl=zh-TW

Comment: Hie @ADyson,
I checked my Quotas page there I see:
   Calendar API per day         Global      0 / 1,000,000

Comment: yes but you asked the question nearly 24 hours before you posted that comment...sure you didn't exceed it the previous day?

Comment: it never exceeded 1,000,000 per day.

Comment: Then you'd probably better ask Google support why it happened, if you think it was not accurate.